# In AngularJS, what is the correct way to filter an array based on odd or even $index property?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to filter an array based on even and odd `$index` property and I want to add odd elements in a separate div and even elements in another div, I could easily do this in JavaScript or jQuery, but I wanted to know the correct way to implement the same in AngularJS.

This is what I've done so far:

```
<div ng-app> 
    <div ng-init="names=['John', 'Mary', 'Cate', 'Suz']">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="name in names">
            <div class="col-xs-6" ng-show="(($index + 1)%2) == 0">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6" >{{name}}</div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

It shows empty spaces in place of odd elements in first case, and when I add the odd expression for second div, the elements in the second div disappear and appear in first div. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VEbsU/) for the same issue.

Please advise.

**EDIT:**

I have got what I wanted, I split the main array into two different arrays odd and even array; this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PzUsH/)** may be useful for people who stumble upon the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have some trouble with what you're looking to do, due to the way `ng-repeat` works. It generates a new scope for each iteration of the repeat. So you'll end up with two divs each time through the loop, one visible and one hidden.

To explain the weird behavior you've been seeing:

- In your first case, the loop is alternating between showing two divs and showing one div. In a row that displays only one div, it understandably looks like a blank was inserted in the second column.
- In the second case, the ng-repeat loop alternates between showing the first div and the second one. Without some CSS styling to show the difference, it looks like one div. You can make it pop by adding a style such as `text-info` to one of the divs.

I hope that explains what's going on behind the scenes, but the better question is... what are you trying to accomplish with the two divs?

**Update:** Since it looks like your goal is to take that array and pump it out into a 2-column layout, you can probably do away with your row div and your 2 column divs. Instead, try repeating a single 6-width column div. It'll handle the row wrapping for you every other column. You can use odd and even styling as @Blackhole pointed out if you want to differentiate the divs. I've got an example fiddle set up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KYTXE) that may be of use.

Comment: I want to add my even position objects to one div and odd position objects to another, its more like a 2 column grid view

Comment: I've updated my answer and included a fiddle that may help you. I think your original attempt is more complex than necessary, but of course it's also possible that I'm oversimplifying it!

Answer (score 5):

Since Angular 1.2.0-rc1, [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) exposes the `$odd` and `$even` properties on the local scope. You can simply use an [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) based on one of this properties:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsList" ng-switch="$even">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">{{item}} is even</div>
    <div ng-switch-default>{{item}} is odd</div>
</div>
```

Notice that if you just want to change the class based on the parity, [ngClassOdd](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClassOdd) and [ngClassEven](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClassEven) are available since 1.0.0:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsList" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

<kbd>[All-in-one Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/wSygh/)</kbd>

Comment: How can I split the main array in two arrays with odd and even elements in the controller?

Comment: In the controller? That's pure javascript: a loop and you're good. But why do you want to make that? If `ngSwitch` doesn't suit your needs, you can use `ngIf` as well.

Comment: It doesnt do what I want, I updated your code here, the second column is empty http://jsfiddle.net/VEbsU/2/

Comment: Can't understand what you want. Please update your question with an exemple of what you're trying to achieve, and the external libraries eventually used.