# Can I filter ng-repeat with the $odd or $even properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to auto filter an `ng-repeat` list by even index. Is it possible to do this somehow? Here's what I am trying but it isn't working:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="thing in things | filter:$even" >
     <div>{{thing.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Is there a proper way of achieving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In AngularJS, what is the correct way to filter an array based on odd or even $index property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502066/in-angularjs-what-is-the-correct-way-to-filter-an-array-based-on-odd-or-even-i)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This will show $even names of the things list.

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-if="$even">
    {{thing.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Updated:**

Or write a predicate function: 
[Working exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/eQWJ6/2/)

Docs: [`ngRepeat`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="thing in things | filter:filterEvenStartFrom(0)">
    <div>{{thing.name}}}</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.filterEvenStartFrom = function (index) {
    return function (item) {
        return index++ % 2 == 1;
    };
};
```

---

**Original:**

How about this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-hide="$even">
     <div>{{thing.name}}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I went for the filter function. Seems obvious now but thank you that did the trick.

Comment: I didn't down vote but ng-if is better it because doesn't render the item.  ng-hide will render the item and hide it.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) of `ng-repeat` tells us about the special properties we can use in such case. You can use:

- `$even` -> true if the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false).
- `$odd` -> true if the iterator position $index is odd (otherwise false).

---

#### Code examples:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-if="$even">
     <div>{{thing.name}}</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div data-ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-if="$odd">
     <div>{{thing.name}}</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div data-ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-class="{'my-odd-class': $odd}">
     <div>{{thing.name}}</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div data-ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-class="{'my-even-class': $even}">
     <div>{{thing.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Humberto but with a conditional comparison

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [0,1]" class="column_{{ i }}">
  <div ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-if="$even == ( i == 0 )">
    {{thing.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can set condition like this:  [ng-if="evenOddExpression ?$index %2!=0 : $index%2==0" ] here you should set [evenOddExpression] value to either true or false from controller.